# How can I apply a divide-and-conquer approach when implementing a Binary Search Tree (BST)?

Tags: computer-science

I'm unfamiliar with Binary Search Trees, but I've been told that applying a divide-and-conquer approach can be useful when implementing them. How can I apply this approach to, for example, find the height of a BST?

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific on what's your question?

Comment: This is something that can be found on Wikipedia. It covers traversal of this data structure.

Answer (score 2):

The name "divide and conquer" comes from military science, and means that you split the enemy up into pieces and conquer the pieces separately. In algorithms, however, often you're not trying to finish each piece on its own- instead, you want to produce a *single* answer. So the template is a bit different. Here's how divide and conquer goes:

1. Split the problem up into pieces.
2. Solve each individual piece by recursively applying this whole process to each piece.
3. Combine the solutions in some way to produce an answer.

The trick is to come up with a clever way to divide the problem so that combining the solutions is possible. You don't need to actually worry about how to solve each smaller piece, because the whole algorithm is the solution! This is a bit magical, but becomes natural as you become more familiar with recursion.

Let's address your problem of finding the height of a BST. Just assume that somehow by magic you're able to find the height of the left subtree and the height of the right subtree. Once you have these two values, can you think of a way to combine them to find the height of the whole BST? If you don't immediately see the answer, think of all of the functions of two integers that you're familiar with, to give you ideas.

You do need a base case for the recursion, but other than that we have the entire solution, believe it or not:

```
int BST_height(root) {
    if(root is a leaf node)
        return 1;
    else
        return mystery_function(BST_height(root.left), BST_height(root.right));
}
```